# How to expose elastic kubernetes cluster in Googlecloud to external ip?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I have setup a kubernetes cluster of elasticsearch in GCP.

```
kubectl get svc
```

gives me

```
NAME                                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
ipgram-elasticsearch-elasticsearch-svc   ClusterIP   10.27.247.26   <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP   2h
```

How to set an external IP for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the service to be of type `LoadBalancer` which will assign an external IP to the LB or `NodePort` and then use the nodes IP.

Comment: I want  to run it in a single node how to run it

Comment: As @codebreach mentioned, by using LoadBalancer service type instead of ClusterIP. This is an easiest way to expose your service onto an external IP address. Please check official documentation for all other options for publishing your services (kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/…)